# How to return two values from a function in C++?

Tags: c++

How to return a integer and a vector from a function. In c++11 I can use tuple. But I have to use C++98 standard.

problem is like this,

```
int myfunction(parameter 1,parameter 2)
{
   vector<int> created_here;
   //do something with created here
   return int & created_here both

}
```

How can I do that. By the way, I have to use my function recursively.So
I have thought a way like this,

```
int n;
vector<int> A;
int myfunction(int pos,int mask_cities,vector<int> &A)
{
    if(mask = (1<<n)-1)
        return 0;
    vector<int> created_here;
    int ans = 999999;
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
       int tmp = myfunction(pos+1,mask|1<<i,created_here);
       if(tmp<ans){
            A = created_here;
            ans = tmp;
       }
   } 
   return ans; 

}
```

will this work? Or there is a better solution.
and By the way, My actual problem is finding the solution of the travelling salesman problem.that should clarify my needs

Comment: That still has `std::pair`.

Comment: In case you didn't parse chris' comment, C++98 has `std::pair<>` if all you need return is two values. and my 2-cents, you better have a bail-out clause in that recursive function, or you'll be quickly reaching your callstack limit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [**`std::pair<>`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair):

```
std::pair<int, std::vector<int> > myfunction() {
    int i;
    std::vector<int> v;

    return std::make_pair(i, v);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use a data structure.

```
struct MyParam
{
    int myInt;
    vector<int> myVect;
} ;

MyParam myfunction( MyParam myParam )
{
    return myParam;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't be a good choice to create a vector in your function and using it if you would be making recursive function calls.

I would suggest you to pass these 2 parameters by reference from your main function(rather than declaring it globally(as OP did) and manipulate them as you go calling the function recursively rather than returning them in each call.